# ExtJS Tree multiple Models (nested)

Tags: extjs, tree, extjs4

I have a tree that is loading asynchronously. I have two models, Manager and User.

Managers can be parent nodes or leaf nodes, but Users can only be leaf nodes. So, a Manager can have any number of Managers above or below him, but I User can only be the child of a Manager.

I have set up proxies for the User and Manager models and set Manager as the TreeStore's Model parameter. I tried using hasMany and belongsTo to describe the relations, hoping that every time I expand a node, a get for Users and for Managers is sent. It isn't working. I'm only getting Managers, not Users.

Anyone have any tips for working with these kinds of relationships?

Comment: Afaik you need to send some parameters to your server so it could determine which node is opening up. And _afaik_ dealing with tree is a pain in ***. Perhaps you can share your code so we could help you out.

Comment: I had the same problem several days ago. After searching I found out that ExtJS 4 TreePanel will only support one model according to this answer on the sencha forum, take a look at answer #8, it's from a sencha developer: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?130060-Ext-4-trees-a-step-forward&p=590905&viewfull=1#post590905

Comment: Just an update on this since it is getting some views. I ended up using a separate call for populating the tree and passed in a parameter for each node that identifies it as a Manager, User, etc. Then the appropriate store is also updated whenever a CRUD operation is made on the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Create new model 'Employee' that will have a property (`IsUser`) and load into list both managers and users IE:

```
   Ext.regModel('Employee', {
        fields: [
            { name: 'ID', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'Name', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'LastName', type: 'string' },
            //....
            { name: 'IsUser', type: 'int' }
        ]
    });
```

And SQL query for populating should look like this:

```
SELECT id, name, lastname, 0 as IsUser

FROM managers ...

UNION

SELECT id, name, lastname, 1 as IsUser

FROM users ...
```